# c++ makefile cant find directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to run makefile but I cant make him find the files I add to it unless I put full path of the file: /home/"user_name"/CLionProjects/Ass1/src/main.cpp
I try to run the makefile when I am in Ass1 so as much that I understand the makefile should find the main.cpp .

Would love to know where I am wrong here, thank you.

what I write:

```
all: clean compile link

link:
    g++ -o /bin/main /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/bin/main.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/bin/Workout.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/bin/Trainer.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/bin/Studio.o

compile:
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/main.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/src/main.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Studio.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/src/Studio.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Workout.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/src/Workout.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Trainer.o /home/daniel/CLionProjects/Ass1/src/Trainer.cpp

clean:
    rm -f bin/*
```

what I want to write and cant:

```
    all: clean compile link

link:
    g++ -o /bin/main /bin/main.o /bin/Workout.o /bin/Trainer.o /bin/Studio.o

compile:
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/main.o /src/main.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Studio.o /src/Studio.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Workout.o /src/Workout.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/Trainer.o /src/Trainer.cpp

clean:
    rm -f bin/*
```

the error I get:

```
rm -f bin/*
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -o bin/main.o /src/main.cpp
g++: error: /src/main.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:7: compile] Error 1
```

Comment: This is not how you write makefiles. Targets that produce files (`compile`, `link`) must be named after the files they produce, and all other targets should be marked as [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html). `clean` and `compile` shouldn't be included in `all`.

Comment: Do you mean it stops working if you replace `/home/ass1/bin/main.o` with `bin/main.o`? Can you show the exact log and error messages?

Comment: lets say that for every file I put there if I dont add the full path it just dont recognize it. so if I put the absulute path of the main.o file it will work and find it but the problem starts even before when trying to create the o file from the cpp file as it does not find him first. this is the error: "g++: error: /src/main.cpp: No such file or directory
"

Comment: `/bin/main.o` is an absolute path, did you mean `bin/main.o`? The error message mentions `/src/main.cpp`, while the makefile only has `src/main.cpp`, are you sure this is the exact makefile? Also please provide the entire output you get when running `make`.

Comment: edited and explained again, hope its more clear now

Comment: Yes, this is better. But again, `/src/main.cpp` is an absolute path, you want `src/main.cpp`.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you to read some Make tutorials. This is not how you write makefiles. You use Make as a fancy way to run sequences of commands, but you might as well use shell scripts for that. A properly written makefile would let you parallelize builds; and when you change parts of your code, rebuild only the modified parts of your project.

Comment: Where are you when you run `make`? That is, what is your working directory?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat first of all thank you so much that worked! and thanks for the input. tbh I just received this form of make file from my course department, but I will look up for making a better one. thank allot again!